# Implementing an abstract generic method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract

I have an abstract generic method in a abstract class:

```
/**
 * @param <Value>
 */
public abstract class TestAbstract<Value> {

    public abstract <Value> void test(Value value);

}
```

Now I extend from this class and implement the abstract generic Method - this is my attempt, but this is obviously wrong.

```
public class Impl extends TestAbstract<Integer> {

    @Override
    public <Integer> void test(Integer value) {

        // value is instanceOf as java.lang.Object and not java.lang.Integer !

    }

}
```

Within `test()` `value` is treated as `Object` and not as `Integer`...

How can I override this Method, so that I am forced to use the 'integer'-Class?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `Value` an actual class in your project?

Comment: No. I want value to be a parameter for this abstract class...

Comment: @peddn: It's a bit unclear what you mean with "treated as `Object`", can you be more specific?

Comment: value is a instance of 'Object' and not a instance of 'Integer'.

Comment: if you mean `int`, that is not possible with generics.

Comment: @peddn: Well because of inheritance, `value` is an [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and thus also `Object`, `Serializable` and `Comparable<Integer>`. If you're talking about `int` (that's something different). You can't

Comment: @MightyPork But java.lang.Integer should be possible or not?

Comment: @CommuSoft But `value` has no access to the java.lang.Integer methods. Its an instance of java.lang.Object and nothing more...

Comment: @peddn: It's solved I think, by saying `<Integer>` in the method, the compiler interpreted this as a *generic method* (with `Integer` a type-parameter). See pbabcdefp's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are replacing the type parameter with a concrete type. You probably intended to do something like this:

```
public abstract class TestAbstract<V> {
    public abstract void test(V value);
}
```

(note that, by convention, type parameters should be a single uppercase letter, if possible)

Now, when you create a concrete implementation of this class, you can substitute a concrete type for this type parameter:

```
public class Impl extends TestAbstract<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void test(Integer value) {
        // Here, "value" is an Integer
    }
}
```

In this case, you don't need a type parameter for the method itself, because it is defined in the surrounding context (namely, in the class).

Comment: @Marco13 - You wrote that "you don't need a type parameter for the method itself."  _Can_ you do this at the method level instead of at the class level, or must this be done at the class level?

Comment: @risingTide It's possible at method level, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: @Marco13 Sorry, I was unclear.  I know that it is possible overall, but I wondered what a method level implementation would look like in  specific example above.  I see that your response has taken it to a class level implemenation; is there a method level implementation for this particular issue?

Comment: @risingTide At least, you can't fix the type in a subclass in this case. For details, consider asking about your particular use case in a separate question (if a similar question was not asked before)

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks, that's enough related to this question.  If I would post my own example it would be exactly the same code as above anyway, which I why I asked here; I didn't want to duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

`test` in `Impl` is not intended to be a generic method. It should only apply to the class `Integer`. Therefore you simply need to change

```
public <Integer> void test(Integer value)
```

to

```
public void test(Integer value)
```

Comment: Indeed, here it is seen as a *generic method*, well spotted! Perhaps you should provide a link to generic methods to make it more clear...

Answer (score 1):

Change the abstract to this:

```
public abstract class SuperClass<T> {
    public abstract void test(T value);
}
```

And the subclass to:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass<Integer> {
    public void test(Integer value) {
    }
}
```

And it works now, as there is no longer a parameter hiding issue.